# Gatling - Reading JSON file and sending content using ElFileBody to a method

Tags: scala, gatling

I am new to Scala and Gatling.

I am trying to write framework for Load and performance testing using Gatling API in Scala for REST API endpoints.

I have a query regarding one of the code snippet which is supposed to generate signature(calling another method) and save the value in the session.

```
.exec(session => {
session.set("sign", SignatureGeneration.getSignature(key, ElFileBody("abc.json").toString()))
                      })

abc.json -
{"device": "${device}"}
```

In above code getSignature takes arguments `(String, String)`. I want to read the json file and replace ${} value in it with the feeders and send it as String to the method.

While debugging the code I found out, ElFileBody send object as `<function1>` and not the json content of it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution -

val bodyExpr = ElFileBody("abc.json")

val bodyStr = bodyExpr(session).get